# Objective-C (senders)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have tableView with custom cell which has a segmentControl. I need for each cell to catch state her segmentControl. I have already my head is spinning, I can't find the error. Can you help me?

**h. file segmentControl:**

```
 @property (nonatomic) NSIndexPath *button_indexPath;
```

**m. file cell:**

```
    - (IBAction)changed1:(id)sender{
       NSInteger i = self.segmentMeating.button_indexPath.row; }
```

**m. file with table view:**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        cell.segmentMeating.button_indexPath = indexPath;
        [cell.segmentMeating addTarget:nil action:@selector(changed1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: I think you might have to implement some delegate to get each segmented control for each row

Comment: Also keep in mind that table view reuse cells. Every time you call `addTarget:action: ` you add one more listener

Comment: @vichevstefan It was self, nil - result of searching error

Comment: @Claudio it turns out that it does. using the declared field button_indexPath

Comment: Can you change it to segmentMeeting? I assume this is about someone meeting, not about meat, sausages, fish etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your m. file with table view, the `segmentMeating`target should not be the `tableView` (self), but the `cell`:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        cell.segmentMeating.button_indexPath = indexPath;
        [cell.segmentMeating addTarget:cell action:@selector(changed1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Because, your target action is in the `Cell` class.T

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use protocol and delegate methods.
In your cell.m create a delegate name:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView segmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentControl changedValueAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Then call it in you cell.m

```
- (IBAction)changed1:(id)sender
```

Then implement it in you tableview.m and you get the modify value because you have the segmentControl in param.

Comment: Thank you for helping, it's working at iOS8 and doesn't work at iOS7. I still need to support earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the `NSIndexPath` of the `UISegmentedControl` that fired your `changed1` function via the `valueChanged` event then you'll know exactly where the action fired from. There's no need to store the indexPath as a variable like you're doing.

```
// Place this in your viewController
- (IBAction)changed1:(id)sender{
    CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView]; 
    NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
    // Now you know exactly which segmented control actually fired this action. 
}

// Set self as the target
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //
    [cell.segmentMeating addTarget:self action:@selector(changed1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    //
}
```

Comment: I can get the cell number in which the change occurred segmentControl, but I am not able to cause an action to get the state of this segmentControl.

Comment: What do you mean you can't cause an action? Is the changed1(UIControlEventValueChanged) event firing? If not, did you set the addTarget:self?

Comment: it's working at iOS8 and doesn't work at iOS7. At ios7 after execution change1 get it: [ViewController changed1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Where are you placing the changed1 IBAction? This needs to be outside of your cell class. You'll be using this action to get the indexPath of the segmentedControl.

Comment: With the help of .h segmentControl I can get the number of the active cell, with the help of the .m with tableView I send a request to perform an action with the contents of the cell specified for .h segmentControl number. And finally, with the help .m cell I perform the necessary actions in change1 already obtained content and numbers. But the solution is already found, look in the top of the page.

Comment: "why addTarget nil? ". This was a key question to the original question. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: /@vichevstefan It was self, nil - result of searching error/  as it turned out, was looking for near